# Laravel 8 with Backpack - datetime formatting on the frontend?

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently trying to format a datetime object that I access like this:

**Blade:**

```
{{ $event->start }} and {{ $event->end}}
```

this outputs something like this on the frontend blades: 
`2021-12-02 22:30:00` ($event->start) 2021-`2021-12-02 23:00:00` ($event->end)

the formatting above is also how it is stored as a `DATETIME` object in the database.
[image]

[image]

Because I use other elements, like a fullcalendar, I dont want to change the way the database stores the dates, just formatting the dates on the frontend/controller directly.

**Controller:**

```
if ($course == 'course') {
    $view   = 'pages.course.current_course';
    $id     = '8';
}

// get the course data from the database
$events = DB::table('eventaries')
    // map the current view $id to the database query
    ->where('category', $id)
    // check if event is expired
    ->where('start', '>', now())
    ->get();


// pass through the data to the correct views
return view($view, [
    "events" => $events
]);
```

But I need the following formatting:
 `Sunday. 12th December 2021, 22:30` ($event->start) and `23:00` ($event->end)

I already got the formatting in the BackPack Backend right by adding `'format' =>` to the CrudController, like this:

**CrudController:**

```
CRUD::addColumn([
    'name'              => 'start',
    'label'             => 'Start',
    'type'              => 'datetime',
    'format'            => 'DD.MM.Y - H:mm',
]);

CRUD::addColumn([
    'name'              => 'end',
    'label'             => 'End',
    'type'              => 'datetime',
    'format'            => 'DD.MM.Y - H:mm',
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Model defined for that particular table. you can define accessor for those two column, like

```
public function getStartAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->toDayDateTimeString();
}
```

It will return output something like **Mon, Nov 29, 2021 05:45 PM**

Define these type of function for `end` column.

[Refer this Carbon Document for other format and date operation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

If you don't have `Model` you can use `Carbon` class in blade or controller directly

Answer (score 0):

We will use `createFromFormat()` and `format()`, `createFromFormat()` will take two argument first give format of date and second one date and `format()` take one argument give formate as you want. you can see bellow examples:

Example 1:

```
  $post->created_at->format('d-m-Y');
```

Example 2:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('d-m-Y')
```